# create a block diagonal matrix involving many matrices

Tags: r, matrix

Now I have many matrices,e.g. $M1$, $M2$, $\cdots$ $M_{n}$, I want to create a diagonal matrix with those matrices as its diagonal elements.
Actually, I know how to do that for few matrices, for example, three matrices, but for many matrices, I do not know how to do that.
In this website, some answer has been posted for few matrices, for example,

```
a <- matrix(1:6, 2, 3)
b <- matrix(7:10, 2, 2)
library(magic)
adiag(a,b)
```

Comment: are they contained in a list? `?Matrix::.bdiag(lst)` Or (worse) are they lying around in your workspace as `M1`, `M2`, `M3`, ... ? or ... ?

Comment: @Ben Bolker Thank you Ben for your re-editing my question, this is my first time to post question, I need to learn more about formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I can use "for loop" to get those n matrices, then I can store them in a list, then to use  `as.matrix(bdiag(list))` will give me what I want.